# Post с использованием сURL

Tags: c, json, post, curl

С целью самообучения хочу выполнить POST запрос но получаю в ответ (здесть часть ответа):

```
  <!-- This file lives in public/404.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <div>
      <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
      <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
    </div>
    <p>If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Запрос выполняю на https://api.myjson.com/bins/1fe5ix. Перечитал несколько раз [документацию](http://myjson.com/api) не но ничего не помогло.

Выполняю запрос так:

```
static const char *postthis = "{\"recipe\"=\"kek\"}";

struct curl_list *header = NULL;

int
postWindowRealized( PtWidget_t *widget, ApInfo_t *apinfo, PtCallbackInfo_t *cbinfo ){
    widget = widget, apinfo = apinfo, cbinfo = cbinfo;
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

      curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

      curl = curl_easy_init();
      if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.myjson.com/POST/bins/s8lt5");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postthis);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);

        header = curl_slist_append(header, "Expect:");
        header = curl_slist_append(header, "Content-Type: application/json");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
        if(res != CURLE_OK)
          fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                  curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
      }
      curl_global_cleanup();

    return( Pt_CONTINUE );
    }
```

**UPD:** После предложенного варианта от zed действительно заработало с одним нюансом - в ответе от сервера не отображается url созданого документа. Нужно писать [сallback](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/post-callback.html)?. В ответ получаю такое:

```
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Status: 201 Created
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< ETag: "c3a475cc94d0934fe7ab1a49b28e54f8"
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
< X-Request-Id: e4015eff-37c7-4e4a-a39c-e0f9bc7d7270
< X-Runtime: 0.006271
< X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.40
< Date: Fri, 22 Sep 2017 06:34:30 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.5.8 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.40
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.myjson.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: Чтобы получить ответ сервера в виде данных, а не принта в консоль, действительно надо использовать callback. Но не тот, что у вас по ссылке, а вот этот: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/getinmemory.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, в json в качестве разделителя используется двоеточие, а не знак равно.

Во-вторых, в документации к API Myjson написано, что запросы надо отправлять на адрес `https://api.myjson.com/bins`

Тестовый код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <curl/curl.h>

void do_post(const char *url, const char *data)
{
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);

    curl = curl_easy_init();

    if(curl) {
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);

        struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept: application/json");
        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

        res = curl_easy_perform(curl);

        if(res != CURLE_OK)
            fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                    curl_easy_strerror(res));

        curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    }

    curl_global_cleanup();
}


int main()
{
    do_post(
        "https://api.myjson.com/bins",
        "{\"recipe\": \"kek\"}"
    );

    return 0;
}
```

Результат запроса:

```
*   Trying 192.73.252.244...                                                                                    
* TCP_NODELAY set                                                                                               
* Connected to api.myjson.com (192.73.252.244) port 443 (#0)                                                    
* ALPN, offering http/1.1                                                                                       
* Cipher selection: ALL:!EXPORT:!EXPORT40:!EXPORT56:!aNULL:!LOW:!RC4:@STRENGTH                                  
* NPN, negotiated HTTP1.1                                                                                       
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384                                                        
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol                                                                      
* Server certificate:                                                                                           
*  subject: CN=api.myjson.com                                                                                   
*  start date: May 15 00:00:00 2017 GMT                                                                         
*  expire date: May 15 23:59:59 2019 GMT                                                                        
*  issuer: C=US; O=GeoTrust Inc.; CN=RapidSSL SHA256 CA                                                         
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.               
> POST /bins HTTP/1.1                                                                                           
Host: api.myjson.com                                                                                            
Accept: application/json                                                                                        
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8                                                                   
Content-Length: 17                                                                                              

* upload completely sent off: 17 out of 17 bytes                                                                
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created                                                                                          
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8                                                                 
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked                                                                                    
< Connection: keep-alive                                                                                        
< Status: 201 Created                                                                                           
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN                                                                                   
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block                                                                               
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff                                                                               
< ETag: "292082b21d0692cbc4b6931f76a7f361"                                                                      
< Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate                                                            
< X-Request-Id: b52281ee-86e8-457e-86b8-658db08f63ab                                                            
< X-Runtime: 0.004854                                                                                           
< X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger 4.0.40                                                                        
< Date: Thu, 21 Sep 2017 12:03:25 GMT                                                                           
< Server: nginx/1.5.8 + Phusion Passenger 4.0.40                                                                
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *                                                                                
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true                                                                        
<                                                                                                               
{"uri":"https://api.myjson.com/bins/r8ma9"}* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0                              
* Connection #0 to host api.myjson.com left intact
```

Видно, что сервер успешно создал документ и вернул его адрес:

```
{"uri":"https://api.myjson.com/bins/r8ma9"}
```

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Comment: Исправил.Спасибо!